# J language. I want express result in form of function

Tags: j

```
(+/%#)0:`(>:@$:)@.(3 :'?2')"0 i.10000
```

Works as I suppose.
Answer tends to 1.
Now I want to express this result in form of

```
f =: (+/%#)0:`(>:@$:)@.(3 :'?2')"0 i.
f 10000
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "Doesn't work"?

Comment: throws error / wrong result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Implicit vs Explicit Composition

Stringing several verbs together via juxtaposition in J doesn't create a pipeline, it creates a "[verb train](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dictf.htm)", which has different semantics.

That is, the *noun phrase*:

```
foo bar bar buz 10000
```

is distinct from the *verb phrase*:

```
f =: foo bar baz buz
f 10000
```

If you want a verb pipeline, you must use some form of [explicit composition](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/samp13.htm) (i.e. denoted, instead of implied).

Most frequently, pipelines are composed of monadic verbs (converting one input to one output, which becomes the input to the next verb), so we use `@:` (or `@`, but using that requires somewhat more attention to detail), so the verbal equivalent to the original noun phrase would be:

```
f =: foo @: bar @: baz @: buz
f 10000
```

#### Composition and Anonymous Recursion

Given that, in your case, we might be tempted to naively write:

```
(+/%#) @: (0:`(>:@$:)@.(3 :'?2')"0) @: i.
```

Taking care to wrap the middle verb (`` 0:`(>:@$:)@.(3 :'?2')"0 ``) in parentheses, because we want to apply that verb, and only that verb, at rank zero (`"0`), and in particular apply the mean (`+/ % #`) to the entire results, not to each individual result.

But if we do that, and run it, we quickly run into a problem: **infinite recursion**.

In the original noun phrase, the verb `` 0:`(>:@$:)@.(3 :'?2')"0 `` stood alone, and therefore the `$:` (anonymous recursion) in that verb referred to `` 0:`(>:@$:)@.(3 :'?2')"0 `` and only to `` 0:`(>:@$:)@.(3 :'?2')"0 ``.

However, once we reformulated the train of three verbs into a pipeline (`f`, above), then `$:` became embedded within `f` and therefore *refers to `f`*.

Meaning,  in this formulation of `f`, when `$:` recurses on a 1, first, `i.` gets applied to that 1, resulting in `,0`, then `?` generates a random bit, which has a 50% chance of being a 1, which then `$:` recurses on, which `i.` is applied to....

This is a well-trod pitfall in J. There are two traditional resolutions.

#### Isolation of $:

You can break your code into smaller, named pieces:

```
f          =:  mean @: converge @: i.
  mean     =:  +/ % #
  converge =:  0:`(>:@$:)@.(3 :'?2')"0
```

which, because it isolates the `$:`, ensures it refers only to `converge`.

Similarly, you can embed the `$:` inside a anonymous explicit context, essentially constraining its purview:

```
f =:  (+/%#) @: (verb def '0:`(>:@$:)@.(3 :'?2')"0 y') @: i.
```

This is like putting blinders on `$:`: now it can't see outside the `verb def`. Some tacit purists may balk at this approach, but at one point [the J interpreter itself employed this tactic](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/release/fdot601.htm) when a definition with an embedded `$:` was fixed using `f.`.

#### Solution

Given your use of `3 : '?2'`, you seem comfortable with anonymous explicit contexts.  If that's the case, then maybe it's just worth going whole hog and just capturing your original, unaltered noun phrase as an explicit verb:

```
meanConverge =: verb define
   (+/%#) 0:`(>:@$:)@.(3 :'?2')"0 i. y
)
```

But, if you prefer a purely tacit solution, and want to go whole hog in the *other* direction, we can eliminate even the `3 : '?2'` explicit code:

```
f          =:  mean @: converge @: i.
  mean     =:  +/ % #
  converge =:  0:`(>:@$:)@.(?@2:)"0
```

And, of course, there are ways to rewrite the verb to avoid recursion altogether, but that probably defeats the purpose of the exercise.

Comment: **FAIR WARNING**: I have not tested any of this code.

Comment: Thank you very much for so thorough answer! It's very helpful.